# "T" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору (C2676)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Получаю данную ошибку в явно специализированной функции для аргумента шаблона Matrix. С чем это связано?

```
namespace mathobj {
    template<typename T>
    class TMatrix;

    class Matrix;

    template <class T>
    TMatrix<T> operator*(const TMatrix<T> &m1, const TMatrix<T> &m2) {
        TMatrix<T> tempMul(m1.row, m2.col);
        for (int i = 0; i < tempMul.row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tempMul.col; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < m1.col; k++) {
                    tempMul.arr[i * tempMul.col + j] += m1.arr[i * m1.col + k] * m2.arr[k * m2.col + j];
                }
            }
        }

        return tempMul;
    }

    template <class T>
    class TMatrix {
    private:
        T *arr;
        int row;
        int col;
        ...
        friend TMatrix<T> operator* <T>(const TMatrix<T> &m1, const TMatrix<T> &m2);
    public:
        TMatrix();
        ~TMatrix();
        ...
    };
}

using namespace mathobj;

template <>
TMatrix<Matrix> mathobj::operator*(const TMatrix<Matrix> &m1, const TMatrix<Matrix> &m2) { 
    TMatrix<Matrix> tempMul(m1.row, m2.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempMul.row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempMul.col; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m1.col; k++) {
                tempMul.arr[i * tempMul.col + j] += m1.arr[i * m1.col + k] * m2.arr[i * m2.col + k];
            }
        }
    }
    return tempMul;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего речь идет о том, что оператор `operator +=` или оператор `operator *` не опреден для элементов массива, адресуемого указателем `arr`, и имеющего тип элемента `Matrix`.

То есть вам следует проверить, определены ли операции `+=` и `*` для объектов типа `Matrix`.

Comment: Определены, просто в другом файле.

Comment: @Mecherok Значит, компилируя данный файл со специализацией, компилятор не видит тот файл, где указанные операции для типа Matrix определены.

Comment: да, проблема решалась подключением хедера класса Matrix в TMatrix.h. А другими способами можно решить это? Просто не хочется ради 2 операций подключать один хедер в другой.

Comment: @Mecherok Когда компилятор генерирует специализацию функции, ему необходимо видеть определения всех операций для объектов класса. Иначе объектный код не сможет быть сгенерирован.